# How do I block a user temporarily

Tags: php, block, conditional-statements, visitor-pattern

I want to block visitor between 2 to 5 minutes every 100 view.. if user view 100 page between 2 to 5 minutes then block user, if user view 100 view in 6 minutes then don't block and reset the counter.

I already create the counter script but i have issue with creating the function which can block visitor between 2-5 mint.

I need help to fix this problem... I try to create a if condition but no luck.. help me please...

```
 $sb_current_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Time());
/////////////////// Cookies Encryption //////////////
function encrypt($text)
{
    $key = "E4HD9h4DhS23DYfhHemkS3Nf"; // 24 bit Key
    $iv = "fYfhHeDm"; // 8 bit IV
    $bit_check = 8;
    $text_num = str_split($text, $bit_check);
    $text_num = $bit_check - strlen($text_num[count($text_num) - 1]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $text_num; $i++) {
        $text = $text . chr($text_num);
    }
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, '', 'cbc', '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_generic($cipher, $text);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
    return base64_encode($decrypted);
}
//////////////// Encription end /////////

////// Cookies decription /////
function decrypt($encrypted_text)
{
    $key = "E4HD9h4DhS23DYfhHemkS3Nf"; // 24 bit Key
    $iv = "fYfhHeDm"; // 8 bit IV
    $bit_check = 8;
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, '', 'cbc', '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
    if ($encrypted_text != "") {
        $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cipher, base64_decode($encrypted_text));
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
        $last_char = substr($decrypted, -1);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $bit_check - 1; $i++) {
            if (chr($i) == $last_char) {
                $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, strlen($decrypted) - $i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $decrypted;
}
///////// Coookies decription end /////////////////


//$sb_check_ban_time = date($sb_current_time, strtotime("+20 minute"));
if ($_COOKIE['spamer_check_time'] == "") {
    setcookie('spamer_check_time', encrypt(time()));
}
function time_deff($date2)
{
    $date1 = time();
    //sleep(2000);
    //   $date2 = decrypt($_COOKIE['spamer_check_time']);
    //echo $date2;
    $mins = ($date1 - $date2) / 60;
    //echo $mins;
    return $mins;
}


//$sb_cookie_expiration = time() + 1200;
//echo $sb_cookie_expiration;
if ($_COOKIE['view2'] != "") {
    $explod = explode("-", decrypt($_COOKIE["view2"]));
}
$i_print = $explod[0];
// $i2=$explod[1];
//echo $i2;
$i = 1 + $i_print;
setcookie("view2", encrypt($i . "-123456789")); //// Need to add extra bit to block unwanted text and secure the cookes more..
//
$i = $i++;
//  echo $i_print;
   //echo "empty".decrypt($_COOKIE["spamer_check_time"]);
$spammer_blocker = decrypt($_COOKIE["spammer_blocker"]);
// or $spammer_blocker==""
$mins = time_deff(decrypt($_COOKIE['spamer_check_time']));
  $diff_time = .1; /// User BLock Time
  if ($mins >=1 or $mins <=2) {
    $block_user=1;
  } elseif ($mins >= 2.1) {
    $block_user=2;
  } else {

  }
/*  if (.2>$mint) {
    // echo "not done";
    $block_user=0;
  } elseif (.2 <= $mint) {
    echo "block User";
    $block_user=1;
  } elseif ($mins>=1) {
    echo "reset cookies";
    $block_user=2;
  }*/
if ($block_user==1 and $i_print >= 15) {

    if ($spammer_blocker == "") {
        setcookie("spammer_blocker", encrypt(time()));
        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
          $time_rev = $diff_block_time - $diff_time;
            $round_time = round($time_rev, 2);
            $time_reverse = str_replace('-', '', $round_time);
            echo "Wait " . $time_reverse . " Minuts before using this site..";
        exit(0);
    } else {

        //$sb_check_ban_time = $spammer_blocker;
        $diff_block_time = time_deff($spammer_blocker);
        //echo $diff_block_time;
        //$sb_check_ban_time = date($spammer_blocker, strtotime("+1 minute"));
        if ($diff_time <= $diff_block_time) {
            ///  echo "Delete the IP and cookies";
            setcookie("spammer_blocker", "");
            setcookie("view2", "");
            setcookie("spamer_check_time", "");
        } else {
            //echo "Still Block"; ///  echo "Still Block";
             header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
      //  echo "IP Block for Spaming wait few mint";

            $time_rev = $diff_block_time - $diff_time;
            $round_time = round($time_rev, 2);
            $time_reverse = str_replace('-', '', $round_time);
            echo "Wait " . $time_reverse . " Minuts before using this site..";
    exit(0);
        }

    }
} elseif ($block_user==2) {
    setcookie("spammer_blocker", "");
            setcookie("view2", "");
            setcookie("spamer_check_time", ""); 
            echo "cookies reset";
} else {

    }
```

Comment: Whats "mint" in this context?

Comment: mint is minutes. Also, I suggest you don't store this in a cookie - as it could easily be cleared. Possibly push it to a session on the server...

Comment: unless you already have user management in place, any *solution* will be trivial to get around - so why do you even want to do this in the first place.

Comment: All awnser which place in few hours are not helping me .. so now i am just edit Q with full code which i created...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to know who they are...

For casual users, you can rely on cookies.  But if you are having problem with an abuser, then they will simply ignore your attempt to stop them and not send a cookie.

There are various levels of knowing "who" someone is.

1. ID in URL
2. Cookies
3. IP Address

And they can ALL be overcome with different levels of diffulculty...

1. Way too easy (just spoof a different ID, etc...)
2. Cookies are the same as #1
3. IP addresses are harder to overcome unless you have a botnet or similar

For your case, you should likely block the IP address as it's the only reasonable way for you to get done what you are looking for.

--

Next, you need to be able to keep track of their connections.  `iptables` in Linux has a way to track the number of connections and block for a specific number of minutes after a certian threshold is reached.

Using only PHP, you need to record each hit, and the IP address of that hit.  An SQL database would be one of the more efficient ways of doing this.

If you don't care about history, then simply (mysql):

```
INSERT INTO HitTable SET IP=..., Visits=1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Visits=Visits+1
```

A background crontab could run a query like this every minute?

```
UPDATE HitTable SET Visits = Visits - 10
DELETE FROM HitTable WHERE Visits < 1
```

Finally, when a visitor visits, you would check the database table for

```
SELECT Visits<100 WHERE IP=...
```

AND if that returns True, let them in, else block them.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: what about the people who make every request from a new ip? or the other way when dozens or hundreds share an ip?

Comment: @Gahooa: You give me the best idea what i wanted to use with php/mysql.. but right know i only determinate use with cookies.. i know if any one remove cookies or block cookies can easily bypass the security.. but i need a solution can i easily block the user who view 100 pages in 2-5 minute.. if he/she not then did not block and start over to check user timing and page view.. as i asked in my queastion. (BTW sorry for my ENGLISH.. i am Pakistani...)

Comment: @Muhammad: Cookie only is unreliable because enemy will simply not send cookie and you will not know them apart from a new visitor.

Comment: What would do you do then, @Dagon ? I came here from google with a really similar idea than gahooa had, only without ID in URL (not my case). Maybe rely on other metadata sent, if any, to check besides the IP?

Comment: Update... I know it's been 8+ years, but if anyone intreated here is what I did!! I have used IP, Cookies, and Session at the same time (I used IP and Cookies to detect users, if cookies won't be received then I rely on IP), also I have added the proxy/VPN detect code which blocks user instantly (but some time legit users also got blocked which I had to manually allow the IP). of course I had to use Database

Answer (score 1):

1. Storing the timeout value in a cookie will be absolutely trivial for a user to change/delete the cookie
2. Storing it in a session variable is a bit more reliable, but again - the user could just delete the session cookie, get a new session going, and start reading again.

That being said, you'd do something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (user_should_be_blocked()) {
   $_SESSION['blocked_start_time'] = time();
   header("Location: timeout.html");
}

if ($_SESSION['blocked_start_time'] > (time() - 300)) {
   header("Location: timeout.html");
}

// got here, must not be blocked and/or timeout has expired
$_SESSION['blocked'] = false;
$_SESSION['block_start_time'] = null;

.... continue on
```

Comment: i will use mysql to verify user IP.. now i am just creating the function which can block user for few mint..

Answer (score 1):

I would use the header funciton to redirect them to another page, either empty or just less bankwidth intensive (assuming that's why you're making this anyway). Soemthing like...

```
if ($block_user == 1)
    header("Location: blockPage.php");
```

At the top of all pages you need to block.

Comment: Keep in mind, the header function must be called before ANY output is actually pushed to the page.  It doesn't have to be the first php function, but it does have to come before any echo or prints you might have.

Comment: first i need to check the time is okay if use is between the 2-5 and view 100 pages then  $block_user=1;.. Please check my above code which i edit hour ago.. i need a solution only for i can easily determinate the use time...

Comment: i just miss type.. USE is USER

Answer (score 0):

Edit: actually, come to think of it, (2) is of course not necessary, if 2 people or 2 computers are logged in they'll only consume their alloted amount of views faster..

You can do this provided:

1. A user needs to be logged in to see the pages.
2. <del>You don't allow the same user(name) to be logged in twice with different sessions.</del>
3. You store the count per-user, not per-session or per-ip/whatever.

<del>(2) is not possible with default file based sessions. A custom database or other persistent storage solution is needed in which you can scan for other session-id's of a current user-id. In a database you would just store a user-id field, a custom memcached solution could also be built, etc. To prevent users being locked out of a session they no longer have my solution was always to destroy any old session a user had the moment they log in. Effectively, if it's tried with multiple sessions/ips, they'll have to log in again and again invalidating the previous session.</del>

(3) again some persistent storage with a timestamp+userid+count (in MySQL's case an `INSERT INTO tablename (user_id,time,count) VALUES (<id>,NOW(),1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1` comes to mind to easily increment view counts.

And on every view query the database again and again about how many views the visitor had the last X minutes.